# Building indexed Lua table from CSV data

Tags: lua

I'm trying to create a lua utility to read from a comma-separated format spreadsheet.

This is an example of the comma separated data:

```
Test Mode,Mode Pass,Parameter1,Parameter2,Parameter3
1,1,M1p1p1,M1p1p2,M1p1p3
1,2,M1p2p1,M1p2p2,M1p2p3
1,3,M1p3p1,M1p3p2,M1p3p3
2,1,M2p1p1,M2p1p2,M2p1p3
2,2,M2p2p1,M2p2p2,M2p2p3
```

The difference between Index columns and Data columns will be that Index columns create a sub table array with indices from the column, where Data columns will be table objects.

From the example above:

```
myCSVFileTable.TestMode[1].ModePass[2].Parameter2 == M1p2p2
myCSVFileTable.TestMode[2].ModePass[1].Parameter3 == M2p1p3
```

The function I'm trying to create will look as such:

```
constructTable(file, numIndexColumns)
```

With the user specifying the number of index columns.

So far, I'm using the following code to read the CSV data and place it into a table, indexed by CSV file row.

```
local constructTable = function(filename, numIndexColumns)

   local tbl = csv_to_indexed(filename)
   local ret_tbl = {}

   assert(tbl[1] ~= nil)

   local column_names = tbl[1]
   local ret_tbl = {}

   assert(numIndexColumns < #column_names,
      "Not enough total columns for the specified number of index columns",
      "constructTable")
end
```

So tbl ends up looking like:

```
tbl sequence[6] 
[1] sequence[6] 
    [1] "Test Mode" 
    [2] "Mode Pass" 
    [3] "Parameter1"    
    [4] "Parameter2"    
    [5] "Parameter3"    
[2] sequence[6] 
    [1] "1" 
    [2] "1" 
    [3] "M1p1p1"    
    [4] "M1p1p2"    
    [5] "M1p1p3"    
[3] sequence[6] 
    [1] "1" 
    [2] "2" 
    [3] "M1p2p1"    
    [4] "M1p2p2"    
    [5] "M1p2p3"    
[4] sequence[6] 
    [1] "1" 
    [2] "3" 
    [3] "M1p3p1"    
    [4] "M1p3p2"    
    [5] "M1p3p3"    
[5] sequence[6] 
    [1] "2" 
    [2] "1"     
    [3] "M2p1p1"    
    [4] "M2p1p2"    
    [5] "M2p1p3"    
[6] sequence[6] 
    [1] "2" 
    [2] "2"     
    [3] "M2p2p1"    
    [4] "M2p2p2"    
    [5] "M2p2p3"
```

I'm not sure, at this point, how to build the myCSVFileTable as defined in my example. I'm thinking I need some sort of recursive function to do so. But I just can't seem to get there in my head.

Answer (score 0):

I have this piece of code to read from a csv file. I use it in my **gideros studio** projects. It is coded in lua. This should work out of the box.

```
function loadCSV(file)

    local function csvsplit(line)
        local t, w, l2 = {}, nil, nil

        while #line > 0 do
            w, l2 = line:match("\"([^\"]*)\"[,\r\n]?(.*)") -- Check for quoted string
            if not w then w, line = line:match("([^,]*)[,\r\n]?(.*)") -- Non quoted 
            else line = l2 end
            if not w then break end --Nothing or issue, break

            t[#t + 1] = w
        end

        return t
    end

    local headers, csv = nil, {}

    for line in io.lines(file) do
        f = csvsplit(line)
        if not headers then -- Assume first line is headers
            headers = {} for n, v in ipairs(f) do headers[v] = n end
        else
            csv[#csv + 1] = f
        end
    end

    csv.getField = function(self, row, field) return self[row][headers[field]] end

    return csv

end
--csv=loadCSV("135-bis-bt.csv")
--print(csv:getField(4,"Value"))
--print(csv:getField(7,"Time")
```

At the end of the code you can find some use case.
The first argument is the row and the second argument is the header name.

It is very straight forward: you pass it your csv file and then can manipulate the data however you want. You can also parse the data into a table and more...

Hope this help.
Peace.

Comment: This doesn't really get me the format I need for my Lua table though, which is what I'm truly hung up on.

Comment: hi brian, I am sure this piece of code could work for you. Please give it a try. I have updated my post. PS: I say hello brian at the beginning of my post but it keeps getting deleted!?! Sorry I could not help more.

Comment: Your code ignores the concept of index and data columns as defined in my spec. I appreciate your help, but your code won't work for me.